# This creation of booleans results in an error?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, boolean

Okay, I am trying to create a storage of booleans for a school project. I have this structure.. and I am getting an error with everything that has to do with the first { in every structure with the error

> Error 2   Array initializers can only be used in a variable or field initializer. Try using a new expression instead. Program.cs  34  17  Program

I cannot figure out what is going on... can anyone help me?

```
forwardAttackPossible = new bool [][]
                {
                    {false,false,false,false,false,false,   //MOVE UP 
                           false,false,false,false,false,
                           true,true,true,true,true,
                           true,true,true,true,true,
                           true,true,true,true,true},

                    {false,false,false,false,false,false,   //MOVE UP RIGHT 
                           false,false,false,false,false,
                           true,false,true,false,false,
                           false,true,false,false,false,
                           true,false,true,false,false},

                    {false,true,true,true,false,false,      //MOVE RIGHT 
                           true,true,true,false,false,
                           true,true,true,false,false,
                           true,true,true,false,false,
                           true,true,true,false,false},

                    {false,true,false,true,false,false,     //MOVE DOWN RIGHT 
                           false,true,false,false,false,
                           true,false,true,false,false,
                           false,false,false,false,false,
                           false,false,false,false,false},

                    {false,true,true,true,true,true,        //MOVE DOWN 
                           true,true,true,true,true,
                           true,true,true,true,true,
                           false,false,false,false,false,
                           false,false,false,false,false},

                    {false,false,false,true,false,true,     //MOVE DOWN LEFT 
                           false,false,false,true,false,
                           false,false,true,false,true,
                           false,false,false,false,false,
                           false,false,false,false,false},

                    {false,false,false,true,true,true,      //MOVE LEFT 
                           false,false,true,true,true,
                           false,false,true,true,true,
                           false,false,true,true,true,
                           false,false,true,true,true},

                    {false,false,false,false,false,false,   //MOVE UP LEFT
                           false,false,false,false,false,
                           false,false,true,false,true,
                           false,false,false,true,false,
                           false,false,true,false,true}
                };
```

Comment: Sorry, It is being used in C#.

Comment: The error is extremely clear. It tells you exactly what is wrong and what to do.

Comment: it seems like you need to create a proper data model instead of this horrible monstrosity. I suggest the use of [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx)s which can be combined and used as flags.

Comment: You may want to have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287601(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your syntax like this:

```
 forwardAttackPossible = new bool [][]
            {
                new[] { boolValues },  
                new[] { boolValues },  
                new[] { boolValues }
            }
```

In your example your code should look like:

```
 forwardAttackPossible = new bool [][]
            {
                new [] {false,false,false,false,false,false,   //MOVE UP 
                       false,false,false,false,false,
                       true,true,true,true,true,
                       true,true,true,true,true,
                       true,true,true,true,true},

                new[]  {false,false,false,false,false,false,   //MOVE UP RIGHT 
                       false,false,false,false,false,
                       true,false,true,false,false,
                       false,true,false,false,false,
                       true,false,true,false,false},

                 // and so on... 
            };
```

As the error states that this: `{ false,false,false }` is only valid when you defining a new field or variable like this:

```
bool[] values = { true, false, true };
```

In your case you need to add `new bool[]` or just `new []` to explicitly state that you want to create an array.

Comment: @downvoters care to explain what's wrong with this answer.

Comment: I think you know why :)